# Can I reasonably access a variable of an extending class?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

I have an array of objects from one class that I made, which includes both objects of that type and objects that extend the first object. I want to access a variable that the extending object has that the first object does not, once I know that the object I am talking about is the extending one. A simplified example of this is shown below:

```
public class Parent {
    public boolean isChild=false;
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public int i=5;
    public Child() {
        isChild=true;
    }
}

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent x=new Child();
        if (x.isChild) {
            System.out.println(x.i); //this is what I want to do...
            //... but I get an error because Parent doesn't have a variable called i.
        }
    }
}
```

So, is there any way for me to get around this? (I looked at making a protected static variable but that didn't seem to be what I wanted because I need multiple copies of it.)

Okay, as for how this is actually being used (which I incorrectly didn't include the first time) I am making my own computer programming language for fun. I have an ArrayList of objects that have been created, and allow users of this language to make their own objects as well as use ones that I have made with both java code and code in my language.

I make strings (aka child) in java and have them extend my wafl_object class (parent). This way they can be carried around in that ArrayList without me having to go around with a different array for every object I make. However, I want to accept a String as a parameter for a different class, and I cannot see its value because it is in an object array and I was treating it like an object. I have now fixed this problem by casting it as a String, once I know that it really is one, and then looking at its value. In this situation, it was easier to just cast it, but in others abstactness may have been more usefull.

Comment: There are several answers telling you how you can do this with `instanceof` and casting to `(Child)`, but in real life (where classes represent actual concepts and not just `Parent` and `Child`) this would be almost certainly considered a poor design, and it would be recommended to use polymorphism instead.  The exact way to best do this would depend on the real-world usage, though.

Comment: What's the use case here? Or just language curiosity?

Comment: @ajb Sorry for not answering before, didn't notice these comments... I am making my own computer programming language (just for fun) and have an array of all of the objects that exist. I also have made some objects in java (like arrays and strings) and need to access the value of a string-like class that I made. Because it is an object, I can carry it around in an ArrayList with all the other objects, but it is the only object that has a String value, so this is just a one-time thing.

Comment: Why did you just delete your [recent Swing mouse question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877081/how-to-get-mouse-coordinates-on-a-canvas-without-an-event-in-java) after I already had answered it and as I was working on improving the answer? Most of us don't enjoy wasting time trying to help, just to see our answers disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try something like :

```
if(x instanceof Child){
    System.out.println(((Child)x).i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of testing the type of the object, use polymorphism:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public abstract int getValue();
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return 5;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent x = new Child();
    System.out.println(x.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it doesn't work for my particular case. I have instances of both the Parent and Child classes in my array, which means that if I made the Parent class Abstract, I couldn't use it.

Comment: Make it return a default value, or null (the return type would have to be changed to Integer), or throw an exception. Add a public boolean hasValue() method returning false for the parent and true for the child. Or use the visitor pattern. There are many solutions that can use polymorphism instead of dirty type checks.

Comment: Ugh, covariant arrays

Comment: @WiErD0, if your array has other children of `Parent` in it, how will you that? I think you would benefit from rethinking your solution.

Comment: @jdphenix Why would I care if it has any other children or Parent in it? I want to know if I can access the variable I and do stuff with it if and only if that object is of type Child as well. If I had for example a Child2 that extended parent that was also in the array, it would not be an instance of Child and I would not need to see that variable anyway. So what is wrong with 'dirty type checks'? I would have to write a second class that actually does something to extend Parent, which I would have made abstract, and then would still have to cast in order to access the variables.

Comment: What will actually happen is that you will want to get the field y if the type is Child2, and the field z if the type is Child3. You'll end up with 3 ugly instanceof tests, instead of simply calling a polymorphic getValue() method, that returns the right value based on the actual type of the child.

Comment: @JBNizet What is it that is wrong with 'dirty type checks'? I find that simply casting the class would be much easier than making it abstract and then making methods to be overriden by all of the classes that extend it(which hypothetically could be more than one in the future), and then not be able to use the parent class at all.  Also, I find this to be more 'dirty' than the other solutions because I then have to deal with all of the variables I want getter overrider methods to in Parent, when to Parent those variables are irrelevant, and do not effect it.

Comment: @JBNizet That makes sense. I can see where that would help, and it is indeed a much better solution to the problem than a manual switch statement. I also agree that for others, this would be a better answer, although for me, I am dealing with the width of a Sprite relative to an object so a getValue() method doesn't help very much, mostly because I know that nothing else is going to have to deal with this. However, since my problem is solved, anyone in the future would probably benefit more from this answer, so I will change the solution. ;)

Comment: @WiErD0 if you can provide a more complete description of your use case in your question ( you mention here a "Sprite relative to an object" ) people would be better equipped to answer your question

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `isChild` can be replaced by using `instanceof` instead: `if (x instanceof Child)`. Afterwards, you can safely cast `x` to `Child`: `Child childX = (Child)x`. `childX` then gives you access to `x`.

Generally, checking for types is frowned upon. Normally you should design your functions such that they accept a type that is general enough to do everything they need to do without having to cast to deriving class types.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Although both X.L.Ant and Eran had similar responses that gave the same idea, I found yours to be the most descriptive. I also had never thought about casting objects, I didn't know that one could do it to something other than a primative data type, and I (still) didn't understand exactly how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need your `isChild` variable. You can use `if (x instanceof Child)`. But in order to access `i`, you'll have to case `x` to `Child`.

In addition, don't access a member directly. Data members such as `i` should be `private` and you should access them by getters.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent x=new Child();
        if (x instanceof Child) {
            System.out.println((Child)x.getI());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with `instanceof` and a cast, as described in other answers, but in general it's better to use polymorphism, to define a method that subclasses can override.  The exact way to do this will depend on the exact nature of your program, but here's one possibility, where I'm using `Employee` for `Parent` and `HourlyEmployee` for `Child` (constructors and other logic would need to be filled in):

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    public String getDescription() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class HourlyEmployee {
    private int wage;
    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return super.getDescription() + " [at $" + wage + " per hour]";
    }
}
```

Then the class that uses an `Employee` wouldn't need to test whether it's an `HourlyEmployee`; it just calls `getDescription`, and the method either will or won't include the hourly wage in the result, depending on what class it is.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use parent or use child

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent x=new Child();
        if (x.isChild) {
            System.out.println(((Child)x).i); //this is what I want to do...
            //... but I get an error because Parent doesn't have a variable called i.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, previous answers are correct and around the same point. You MUST let the compiler know that the you want to use (x) as a child and not parent.

So, and sticking with your code sample, the answer is to modify the System.out statement to the following:

```
 System.out.println(((Child)x).getValue());
```

Comment: seems nikpon answered the question while i was writing my own answer (it's the same)